# How to remove blur edges from Frankfurt theme in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, themes

I like this **Frankfurt** theme but I don't like the **blurriness** at the frame title edges. Though there is a lot of themes available for beamer like *boxes, AnnArbor* and has sharp edge. I will be very grateful to you if you help me to fix this problem by set the frame title edges into sharp.

It will also be appreciating if you could remove the shadow from the **Block** and make it's corner radius into 0%.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}    % Frankfurt, boxes, Luebeck, Boadilla, AnnArbor, Antibes
\usecolortheme{crane}    % albatross, crane, 
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\usepackage{bookman}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=false]  % title page
\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------
\section{Section Name}
\subsection{Subsection Name}
%---------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}[c,    % vertical align [c, t, b]  
allowframebreaks,
allowdisplaybreaks]
{This is frame title}
{Frame subtitle}
This is frame content...
\begin{block}{Block title}
This is Block content....
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[default]` you can remove the rounded edges and shadows around the blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Frankfurt` theme uses

- the `smoothbars` outer theme, which is basically the `miniframes` theme plus the colour transitions, so you could directly use the `miniframes` theme
- it calls the `rounded` inner theme with the shadow option -> use it without this option instead

---

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}


\mode<presentation>

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme[shadow=false]{rounded}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}

\mode
<all>


\usecolortheme{crane}    % albatross, crane, 
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\usepackage{bookman}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=false]  % title page


\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------
\section{Section Name}
\subsection{Subsection Name}
%---------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}[c,    % vertical align [c, t, b]  
allowframebreaks,
allowdisplaybreaks]
{This is frame title}
{Frame subtitle}
This is frame content...
\begin{block}{Block title}
This is Block content....
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, it is working. thank you so much @samcarter